# MediaWiki: How can I create users programatically?

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, integration, mediawiki

**Context**

I would like to integrate [MediaWiki][1] as a helping tool to my system. Only the user of my system should have access to [MediaWiki][1]. So if an user sign in or update her account at my system, this change (login and password) should be in sync with [MediaWiki][1].

**Plataform**

.NET application and PHP

**Possible Solution**

MediaWiki extension which provides a webservice for user account managment.

1. Do you have any idea about how can I
   accomplish my **possible solution**
   or any other solution considering
   the **context** I am?
2. If there isn't an existing plugin, how can work
   with the mechanics to do a custom
   solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you all for posting. The answer to my question came about with some insights from you too. But actually, there's no other easy way to create user automatically. I wrote a webservice which handlers the CRUD action for that.

I wouldn't do @tokk suggestion because it is not good to integrate systems architectures through database directly. There's a whole explanation for that.

I wouldn't do @adrian-archer suggestion cause RemoteUser is beyond my context.

Answer (score 1):

If you have acces to your DB you can use the user-table from mediawiki directly. [Here are some informations about this table.](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aUser_table)

Comment: Thanks for answering but I wouldn't like to access the database directly because the password field is encrypted with a PHP function. I could write a PHP webservice as a plugin using the information you gave me. Let me see what other folks say about that. Thanks anyway! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the [Extension:AutomaticREMOTE_USER](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aAutomaticREMOTE_USER) extension.